# Aws s3 time difference issue

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting below issue

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: RequestTimeTooSkewed; Request ID:

Need help already using latest 2.6.18 version sdk of s3

And phone time is synced with network operator which is also correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be fixed if clock skew isn't detected.
by using setTimeOffset() function on AmazonS3Client object

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(Config.Access_Key, Config.Secret_Key));
s3Client.setTimeOffset(3600);
```